# All the new widgets are having the same background image as "centralwidget",how can I rest them?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm using `Qt Designer` and I wanted to insert an image to be as a background to my app so What I did is the following:

```
Right click on 'centralwidget' -> Change styleSheet -> "border-image: url(:/Resources/MyImage.jpg);"
```

The problem is all the widgets( buttons, Labels...) now have MyImage.jpg as a background image. I've read that this is happening because the new widgets are inheriting from `"centralwidget"`. How can I rest them to Default?

Comment: I'm using Qt Designer how can or where i can do that

Comment: Now I have the same problem with the new layouts every layout has that image as a background, Sorry for not making it clear earlier but what I want is to have the image as a background for the window and only the window everything else should be as default

Comment: ;;;;;; Yes! I did

Comment: I Found the solution thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
QWidget#centralwidget{  border-image:url(:/Resources/MyImage.jpg);}
```

This solution worked for me

Comment: the actual stylesheet just needs the id-selector: `#centralwidget { border-image: url(::/Resources/MyImage.jpg)}`.